# Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble in using and decoding Strings Regular Expression.

Here is a pattern, "`(?i)((^[aeiou])|(\\s+[aeiou]))\\w+[aeiou]\\b`",
 and is to matched to `"Arline ate eight apples and one orange while Anita hadn't any`".
Unable to identify the result, as to how.

the question is from Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel, Strings Chapter.

Kindly enlighten.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### Explaination:

- `(?i)` -- means case-insensitive( its allow a-zA-Z)
- `^[aeiou]` -- means start with aeiou
- `|` - uses for or
- `\\s+[aeiou]` -- means match one or more space then [aeiou]
- `\\w+` -- means match one or more word character(a-zA-Z0-9_)
- `\\b` -- means end with word boundary

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/36) here to test match.

#### Java Code:

```
String text = "Arline ate eight apples and one orange while Anita hadn't any";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)((^[aeiou])|(\\s+[aeiou]))\\w+[aeiou]\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

#### Output:

```
Arline
 ate
 one
 orange
 Anita
```

Comment: not just space. *whitespace* character Tab, etc.

Comment: You also forgot the or pipe `|`

Answer (score -1):

`?i` makes it case-insensitive. `((^[aeiou])|(\s+[aeiou]))` means to start a capture group that starts with a vowel [aeiou] or a vowel that starts with any whitespace character `\s`.
Then, one or more whitespace characters `\w+`, that finally ends with a vowel `[aeiou]`

Comment: ?i means case-insensitive not sensitive....